# With C# documentation tags is it possible to persist them through a webservice?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, documentation

With C# documentation tags is it possible to persist them through a webservice so that the webclient that consumes the webservice will display them via the intellisense?

Any information on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Rick

Answer (score 1):

> With C# documentation tags is it
>   possible to persist them through a
>   webservice so that the webclient that
>   consumes the webservice will display
>   them via the intellisense?

No, the webservices do not push the xml document comments from the .net code.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get intellisense in this situation would be to distribute a client access bindings library with the code comments compiled into an xml file.  (i.e. WebServiceAccessLib.dll and WebServiceAccessLib.xml)

Comment: Exactly, you could allow your webservice consumer to download the Xml document file so that they can use it when generating a local proxy. I never did it, but I presume its feasible. An online help file for your service might also be the best.

Answer (score 0):

A good question.  It is certainly not possible out of the box but I don't know feasible it would be to hook into the process the generates the WSDL for the service and add annotation's to the WSDL.  You would also need a proxy generator on the client side to pick up those annotation or documentaion tags when generating the proxy objects.